# ASP.NET Core 2 I am getting an error on my OnModelCreating method after upgrading too Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core

I am transferring files from my 1.1 project to ASP.NET Core 2 and now get an error. After googling the error there is virtually nothing to indicate what it is...

Its in a class library.

The error is:

> 'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Relational' and no extension method 'Relational' accepting a first argument of type 'IMutableEntityType' could be found

on this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
        }
```

I have a squiggly line under "Relational".

Is this as a result of the upgrade? How do I fix it?

I have these usings at the top:

```
        using JobsLedger.MODEL.Entities;
        using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
        using System;
```

Comment: Have you added the - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package to your project? This includes all the required nuget packages. In case you don't want to add all of them ensure you have atleast the nuget 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational ' included.

Comment: Unlike the main project in the solution there is no NuGet folder in the dependencies however when I open the Nuget-solution I have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package, the EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools package, the Microsoft.NetCore.App package and the SisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package..

Comment: I am also getting an error PropertyBuilder<bool> does not contain a definition for "HasDefaultValue" are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference...

Comment: Check the installation documentation for EF Core 2.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/. Ensure everything is as it should be as detailed there. There's likely some package that's missing or some package that shouldn't actually be installed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this and pretty easily in the end.  I noticed in the class library there was no NuGet folder in the Dependencies folder. It was missing completely.

I examined the csproj file and instead of having  references such as Package references it was hard referencing all the way back to the program files directory.  I deleted those references in the csProj file replaced them with a normal list and as a result I now have a NuGet folder and a list of those packages in the normal way.

This is my current csProj file:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\JobsLedger.MODEL\JobsLedger.MODEL.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation">
        <Version>7.2.0</Version>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
      <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
      <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

  </Project>
```

Structuring the csProj file this way the error disappeared and I was able to run my "dotnet migrations" and "dotnet database update" commands as per [THIS](https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/) site successfully resulting in a built database.